# How long is the limitation of the length of the file `/proc/{processId}/cmdline`?

Tags: linux, command

I have a java process and its classpath includes many jars, so the startup command is very long.

Assume that the process id is 110101, when I check the command by command `cat /proc/110101/cmdline`, I find the command is incomplete, it only contains about 4000 characters.

Is there any other method to show the original startup command?

Answer (score 0):

```
 man proc

 /proc/[pid]/cmdline
              This holds the complete command line for the process, unless
              the process is a zombie.  In the latter case, there is nothing
              in this file: that is, a read on this file will return 0
              characters.  The command-line arguments appear in this file as
              a set of strings separated by null bytes ('\0'), with a
              further null byte after the last string.
```

It may not give you all args by cat the file.